# max and min of $f(x,y)=e^{|y|-|x|+1}$ on $D=\{(x,y) \in R^2 : x^2-2x+y^2+2|y| \le 0\}$

Tags: real-analysis

D is a compact domain and f is continuous on D so for Weierstrass' theorem exist global max and min. 
D and the function are symmetric respect x-axis so I study for $y\ge0$.
If I consider $\gamma_1=\{(x,y):y=0,x\in [0,2]\}$ so $f(x,y)=e^{1-x}$ decrescent in $[0,2]$. But for the circumference arc?

Comment: Hint: you only  have to find maximum and minimum  of $|y|-|x|$ on $D$.

Comment: why?because the exponential function is monotone?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **sketch** of a possible analytical way:

- $x^2-2x+y^2+2|y| \le 0 \Leftrightarrow (x-1)^2 + (1+|y|)^2 \leq 2$

It follows immediately that

- $0 \leq |y| \leq \sqrt{2}-1$

Solving the given condition for $x$ shows

- $1-\sqrt{2-(1+|y|)^2} \leq x \leq 1+\sqrt{2-(1+|y|)^2} \stackrel{0 \leq |y| \leq \sqrt{2}-1}{\Longrightarrow} x \geq 0$

Now, using above inequality you get

- $-1 + |y|+ \sqrt{2-(1+|y|)^2} \geq |y|-|x| = |y| - x \geq -1 +|y| -\sqrt{2-(1+|y|)^2}$

Maximizing the LHS and minimizing the RHS on $0 \leq |y| \leq \sqrt{2}-1$ gives

- $\max_{D}(|y|-|x|) = 0$ for $|y| = 0, x = 0$ and $\min_{D}(|y|-|x|) = -2$ for $|y| =0, x = 2$

So, finally you get

- $\max_{D}f(x,y) = e$ and $\min_{D}f(x,y) = e\cdot e^{-2}=\frac{1}{e}$

Answer (score 0):

The contour lines for $f$ are straight lines... Draw them and you will immediately see where the global min and max occur.